# What is the meaning of "pretty decent" in terms of level of quality?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms, idiomatic-language, slang

I have heard this idiom/phrase in various contexts over the last few decades. Yet, it has been difficult to establish an appropriate meaning to it corresponding to more formal language. Probably because it is more slang than used formally. Examples below:

1. "Roger Federer has a pretty decent serve."
2. "Our town has a pretty decent collection of so-and-so branded sports gear."
3. "We had a pretty decent trip down South over the summer."
4. "Hey! This food is pretty decent."
5. "Last night's movie was pretty decent. Not a waste of my money at all."

So, does it mean average, decent, acceptable, satisfactory, fairly good, quite good, good, excellent, above average, what is it specifically? Or, by design, does the meaning change with tone and context, because it is slang?

Comment: "Pretty decent" doesn't have an exact meaning. Yes it can mean almost any of those you listed depending on context, tone of voice, etc.  I understand your frustration in wanting to pin down an exact meaning, but language doesn't always work like that unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is flexible.  It could mean anything from "okay" to "excellent".  British speakers, in particular, tend to use understatement ironically. And as with any ironic use you have to catch the nuance of context and tone of voice to guess the real meaning.

Comment: I agree about British understatement... but using  "pretty decent" ironically? Really? Irony is about opposites, black is white and so on, and "pretty decent" is neither black nor white.